# Function not preserving the old values

Tags: php

This is all the source code, it is a simple form with 2 text fields:

- [index.tmpl.php](http://pastebin.com/SVUQtDWS)
- [index.php and functions.php](http://pastebin.com/PQ4Qb6bk)

The problem I have is in the HTML where it calls the old function:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php old('name'); ?>">
```

The old function code:

```
function old($key)  if( !empty($_REQUEST['$key']))                
    {return htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['$key']); }       
    return '';   
    }
```

For some reason, it doesn't preserve the old values. I cleared the cache and restarted Apache to see if that was the problem but nothing. I ran out of ideas, any ideas why the old function is being ignored?

---

My testing environment: Windows 7, xampp  php5.3, but also uploaded to my test server and same results.

Comment: `$_REQUEST['$key']`.  You have a key named "$key"? I think you mean to use `$_REQUEST[$key]`.

Comment: formatting your code will make the whole difference

Comment: Is there something wrong with the shift key on your keyboard?

Answer (score 5):

You need `<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php print old('name'); ?>">`

or if it supports the shorthand `<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= old('name'); ?>">`

Basically, the function is being called, but it's not being printed anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an opening bracket...

```
function old($key) { 
   if(!empty($_REQUEST['$key'])) {
      return htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['$key']); 
    }       
    return '';   //<---- I think you might need this in else
}
```

Comment: You don't need an else, the return makes the else redundant

Comment: Also, looking at the pastebin, he has the additional parenthesis, it must have got lost in the copt/paste here

Comment: @GlennSlaven I guess he needs to rewrite the whole stuff inshort..I copypasted from the code shared in the question and not from the pastebin

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php print(old('name')); ?>">
```

and php

```
  function old($key) {
      if( !empty($_REQUEST['$key']))                
      {
        return htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['$key']);
       }       
      return '';   
    }
```